# -bash: cbrestore: command not found

Tags: couchbase

I have my couchbase dump in my download directory and I am trying to restore using command for my mac terminal

```
sudo /Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbtransfer /Users/xxx/backup_folder http://root:password@localhost:8091
```

I am getting the response as

```
-bash: cbrestore: command not found
```

I run couchbase from the zip that I have downloaded from couchbase website

Comment: Which version are you running on? If you're using the Couchbase 5.0 Beta then cbrestore was not included in that release, but will be included in the 5.0 GA.

Comment: I am using couchbase version 4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd /opt/couchbase/bin
./cbrestore backup http://localhost:8091 -u 'Administrator' -p 'xxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the default path to couchbase `cbrestore` tool [as mentioned in this doc here](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbtools/cbrestore.html)

Linux :

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/cbrestore
```

Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\cbrestore
```

Mac OS X :

```
/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbrestore
```